# eclipse Run As with Maven dependency not automatically included

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependency-management

I have moved a jdbc dependency to Maven but I still need to add it manually to my Eclipse run config for it to be found at run time using eclipse Run As (see picture). 
What do I need to do for this jar to be added/found automatically at runtime in Eclipse?

[image]

Comment: Please avoid images (e.g., I can't see the image over my standard workplace connection) in favor of text. What Maven plugin are you using?

Comment: I have seen this before, but the newest Eclipse with the newest m2e is much more robust.  Upgrade and try again.  If it keeps being a problem, delete the launch configuration and relaunch.

Answer (score 0):

- The problem was that for some reason the "Maven Dependencies" library was not added to the classpath of my eclipse run config.
- To add the "Maven Dependencies" library I had to copy the following line into my run config file:

> listEntry runtimeClasspathEntry
>   containerPath=org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER

A bit hackish, but works fine now.